# ¿Cuál es la alternativa a la función and() que aparece como deprecated?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

estoy implementado Spring Security en mi proyecto y al implementar la autentificación me marca como "Deprecated" el método and(). He estado buscando información pero no he encontrado la alternativa para poder hacerlo, si alguien me pudiera indicar cual es la manera correcta de hacerlo lo agradecería.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
package com.example.aplicacionwebfilmotokio.security;

import com.example.aplicacionwebfilmotokio.service.impl.UserDetailServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder,
                                                       UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService) throws Exception {

        return http
                .getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)
                .and().build();
    }
```

**El mensaje cuando pongo el cursor por encima del error:** 'and()' is deprecated and marked for removal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes añadir el código como texto? Las imágenes son ilegibles desde un móvil y complicadas de ver en un PC normal

Comment: Ya está, he agregado el código :)

Answer (score 0):

Dado que el método `and()` fue deprecado desde la versión **6.1.0** de Spring Security, tienes 3 opciones:

1. Marcar con `@SuppressWarnings("removal")` tu método `authenticationManager`.
2. Cambiar de versión tu dependencia Spring Security por una menor a la versión **6.1.0**.
3. Aplicar lo que menciona la documentación de [SecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/SecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#and()):

> Use the lambda based configuration instead.